# best way to make a text box that will show text

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, python-3.10

I am new to Python and am using Tkinter to create a basic GUI for a game.
I have got some buttons an image and numerous labels to work, but I am wondering..

What is the best way to get a large, initially blank text box on the GUI, and how would I go about having the text box update on the press of a "next" button.

I need it to scroll through text with each press, showing the next relevant line.
The text that is shown will depend on the choice(s) that are made, so variables like current location etc are necessary.

The aim is to make a simple game that allows you to read through the text with the Next button, then make choices etc, a mostly text-based adventure game.

I'll post what I have already below. Yes I know it's terrible, this is my first try so don't judge too harshly on my mistakes.

Any tips, advice or methods are much appreciated.

Some things to note:

My quit button isn't working yet, not too sure why.
I would love to figure out how to store variables based on what the user inputs, via an input box that can be prompted when an input is required from the user.

Also, happy to start from scratch if it's easier.

```
# Widgets:

import sys     #Imports the system commands which makes it possible to terminate the program
import time    #Imports the time module to allow delays in script
import os      #Imports os to make it possible to play music/sound
import random  #Imports random variable to allow for random number generation
import pickle  #allows the game state to be saved.
from tkinter import * # imports tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from textwrap import wrap # imports text wrap




#base variables for testing
character_Gold = 1
character_Health = 100
character_base_Health = 100
character_Strength = 10
character_Dexterity = 10
character_Constitution = 10
character_Intelligence = 10
character_Wisdom = 10
character_Charisma = 10
character_base_Perception = 10

#Text Boxes

#Base Geometry and image
window = Tk()
TitleScreen = PhotoImage( file = 'test.gif' )
window.geometry("1100x600")

#defines
def close():
    #win.destroy()
    window.quit()

imgLbl = Label( window, image = TitleScreen )
label1 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label2 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label3 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label4 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label5 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label6 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label7 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label8 = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 4)
label9 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label10 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label11 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label12 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label13 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label14 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label15 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
label16 = Label( window, relief = 'groove' , width = 3)
TextLabel = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 50)
LocationLabel = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 18)
LocationBase = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 13)
NextBtn = Button( window )
MainText = Label( window, relief = 'groove', width = 40, height = 8)
QuitButton = Button(window, text="Quit",command=close)


# Geometry:
imgLbl.grid( row = 1, column = 1 , rowspan = 24 ) # Change Rowspan here to increase number of Rows and shrink gaps
label1.grid( row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10 )
label2.grid( row = 1, column = 4, padx = 10 )
label3.grid( row = 1, column = 5, padx = 10 )
label4.grid( row = 1, column = 6, padx = 10 )
label5.grid( row = 1, column = 7, padx = 10 )
label6.grid( row = 1, column = 8, padx = 10)
label7.grid( row = 1, column = 9, padx = 10)
label8.grid( row = 1, column = 10, padx = 5)
label9.grid( row = 2, column = 2, padx = (1, 10)) #Health
label10.grid(row = 2, column = 4, padx = 10) #STR
label11.grid(row = 2, column = 5, padx = 10) # DEX
label12.grid(row = 2, column = 6, padx = 10) # CON
label13.grid(row = 2, column = 7, padx = 10) #INT
label14.grid(row = 2, column = 8, padx = 10) #WIS
label15.grid(row = 2, column = 9, padx = 10) # CHA
label16.grid(row = 2, column = 10, padx= 10) # gold
TextLabel.grid( row = 26, column = 1, padx = 10) # instruction label
LocationLabel.grid( row = 2, column = 11, padx = 10) # dynamic location label, changes
LocationBase.grid( row = 1, column = 11, padx = 10) # location text only not dynamic
MainText.grid( row = 30, column = 1, padx = 10) # main text box
QuitButton.grid(row = 34, column = 14 , padx = 10) #Quit Button

NextBtn.grid( row = 26, column = 2, columnspan = 4 )

# Static Properties
window.title( ' The Adventure ')
NextBtn.configure( text = 'Next')
Current_Location = "Title Screen"


#DynamicProperties. BD is button facelift level, bg is colour.
label1.configure( text = 'HP:', bg = 'Red' )
label1.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label2.configure( text = 'STR:', bg = 'Orange')
label2.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label3.configure( text = 'DEX:', bg = 'Purple')
label3.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label4.configure( text = 'CON:', bg = 'Green')
label4.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label5.configure( text = 'INT:', bg = 'light green')
label5.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label6.configure( text = 'WIS:', bg = 'white')
label6.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label7.configure( text = 'CHA:', bg = 'light blue')
label7.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label8.configure( text = 'GP:', bg = 'yellow')
label8.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
label9.configure( text = character_Health)
label9.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label10.configure( text = character_Strength)
label10.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label11.configure( text = character_Dexterity)
label11.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label12.configure( text = character_Constitution)
label12.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label13.configure( text = character_Intelligence)
label13.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label14.configure( text = character_Wisdom)
label14.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label15.configure( text = character_Charisma)
label15.configure( bd = 6, relief=RAISED)
label16.configure( text = character_Gold)
LocationLabel.configure( text = Current_Location, fg = 'White', bg = 'Black')
LocationLabel.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED) # raises the button up to look 3d
LocationBase.configure( text = "Your Location:", fg = "black", bg = "White") #"location" text above tab that changes actual location
LocationBase.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED)
TextLabel.configure( text = "Welcome To The Adventure. Click 'Next' to begin!") # instruction label
TextLabel.configure( bd = 2, relief=RAISED)
MainText.configure( text = '''This is the large box where \n the main game text should go.''', fg = "Black", bg = "White") # use \n for a NEWLINE
MainText.configure( bd = 10, relief=RAISED)
NextBtn.configure( bd = 8, relief=RAISED) # raises next button
QuitButton.configure( bd = 2, relief=RAISED, text="Quit",command=close)

#Sustain Window:
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `tk.ScrolledText` - see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) for documentation and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-scrolledtext-widget/) for some examples.

Comment: To exit your program do window.destroy() or sys.exit() if you got something running independent of your window. You could use the "Entry" widget provided by tkinter which allows you to put in some text, you could then get the text from a button command or something just run a function that says ´text_entry.get()´ . You can also pass arguments when calling a function that might solve your problem with updating your game based on the users decision.

Comment: @Spicy Joseph. def close():
    window.destroy()
    #window.quit()